# inputting a 2D array in python using Nested Loops

Tags: python, arrays

hello guys I'm new to python and I just wanted to give values to a 2D array using nested loops like how we were doing it in java and etc. but says list index out of range and I don't know how to fix it.

this is my code.

```
prices= [ [] *8] *20
images= [] 

for i in range (1,8):
    images.append(i)

for page in range (8):
    for price in range (20):
        prices[page][price].append(input())
```

I didn't found any things in internet abut this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and asked a lot about it, and they told me it's so easy, I just had to use NumPy library. it done what I wanted so perfect and easy.
like this:

```
images=[]
for i in range(1,9):
   images.append(i)

prices=np.array([])

with open('prices.csv', mode ='r')as file:
   csvFile=csv.reader(file)
   for line in csvFile:
       prices = np.append(prices,[line[0]])
   prices = prices.reshape(8,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define arrays

```
prices = []
images = []
```

And append other array in first array, this will create 2D array

```
for i in range (1,8):
    images.append(i)

for page in range (8):
    for price in range (20):
        prices.append(['test', 1])

print(prices)
print(images)
```

Output

```
[['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], 
['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], 
..........
['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], 
['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1], ['test', 1]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

```
prices[0][0] -> test

prices[0][1] -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `[] *8]`  this statement it will create a list with 8 references to the same empty list. This piece of code will create 8 rows having 20 elements in each.

```
 prices = []
for row in range(8):
    rows = []
    for col in range(20):
        rows.append(input())
    prices.append(rows)
```

Output:

Here adding the picture which shows it creates 8 rows with 20 elements in each.

[image]